# If date in cookie was yesterday, or further away

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie which sets dates for previous visits to my site. It keeps hold of all dates visited for 30 days in the following format:

> 2016-07-13|2016-07-10|2016-06-28

I need to check if a date in this cookie is older than a day. So e.g:

- Today is the 13th
- Cookie shows last visit 13th
- Therefore I want a `false` result. Cookie contains todays date

But:

- Today is 13th
- Last date in cookie was the 12th (e.g `2016-07-12`)
- Cookie contains at least yesterday's date. So `true` result sent

I want to do this as succinctly as I can.

I currently have the following (not very succinct yet):

```
var cookiePreviousSiteVisit = '2016-07-10|2016-07-02|2016-06-28'.split('|');

var todaysDate = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date(previousSiteVisit[0]);

return todaysDate > prevDate;
```

My problem with this is it returns `true` if today's date is in there too. I need to discount 1 day from my calculations. Any advice?

Comment: @MarcB Doesn't Javascript allow simply subtracting 1 from the date itself?

Comment: Try to add `todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)` before the test so that both dates have the same time.

Comment: @PaulStelian: kinda. `var d = new Date() - 1` gives you a millisecond timestamp integer, which you could feed back into another Date() object

Answer (score 2):

Add `todaysDate.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);` before the test so that both dates have the same time, or compare using [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), and [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

The reason `prevDate` is lesser than `todaysDate` even when they refer to the same day is because [`Date`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) also contain time. `todaysDate` will be set to the time `new Date()` has been called. However, `prevDate` is parsed from a string that does not contain any time information. Therefore, its time is midnight (0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds and 0 ms).

```js
function notVisitedToday(){
  var previousSiteVisits = '2016-07-13|2016-07-02|2016-06-28'.split('|');

  var todaysDate = new Date();
  var prevDate = new Date(previousSiteVisits[0]);
  todaysDate.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  return todaysDate > prevDate;
}

console.log(notVisitedToday());
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely getting close. However, I'm receiving `false` using this code for the return. The reason seems to be that `todaysDate` is `Thu Jul 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` but the last visit date is `Wed Jul 13 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` - there's a 1hr time difference

Comment: This is odd. It works fine on the above snippet on my side.

Comment: The reason you got different time is because `setHours` is dependent of your timezone. I edited the answer to use `setUTCHours`.